# Select specific data in REST

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am currently building an nodeJS api using express and mongodb and
i am trying to follow as much as possible the REST approach and
i don't know what is the best way to select the specific data of a resource

For example,
If I have the model user with first name, last name, email and password i would have to use:

```
GET -> http://localhost/users -> To get all users
GET -> http://localhost/users/12 -> To get the user with ID 12
```

If I wanted to select only the first name and last name,
what would be the correct url structure?

This way would be correct ?

```
http://localhost/users?select=firstName,LastName
http://localhost/users/12?select=firstName,LastName
```

Sorry for my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is flawed because it would suggest the user could send a request for the password by simply appending to that csv list of parameters.

Should consider using some other auth services which handle the password management such as sign in with google or Facebook, if the business requirements permit such.

Otherwise you should consider encrypting the passwords before storing them, or using a separate database that has an encryption layer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.

I did not mention anything about my strategy, in fact, I encrypt the passwords with bcrypt and I allow the authentication of the users with facebook and twitter.

What I mentioned about the users was just an example to illustrate my question. I just want to know what is the best way to select data in a api REST, or if it is more convenient for the api to return all data of the resources. Again, sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine with query ?select=...., but you still have to check in your route if that contains req.query.select, then do some logic to response the fields you want.

Comment: Hi Quang Anh Pham, thanks por answering! I'll keep that in mind